# Parameter specified as non-null is null in ArrayAdaper

Tags: android, kotlin

I've extended ArrayAdapter for spinner:

```
class OrderAdapter(context: Context, resource: Int, objects: List<Order>) : ArrayAdapter<Order>(context, resource, objects) {
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View? {
            val view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent)
            view?.let { view.find<TextView>(android.R.id.text1).text = getItem(position).name }
            return view
        }
        override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View? {
            val view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent)
            view?.let {view.find<TextView>(android.R.id.text1).text = getItem(position).name }
            return view
        }
    }
```

I'm getting exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter convertView
                                                                                          at com.github.blabla.endlesss.ui.adapter.OrderAdapter.getView(OrderAdapter.kt:0)
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: The exception is pretty clear. You are passing null for the convertView parameter.

Comment: This method is invoked by the Android framework and the parameter is actually defined as nullable, so nulls should be allowed.

Comment: @Dawid are you sure your code is the same you posted here? Specifically, is the `convertView` parameter really declared as nullable?

Comment: Is super `getView()` with the same signature?

Comment: This was issue with incremental compile. I've rebuild project and it works.

Comment: i've met the same problem. but finally i find that i defined an `Adapter` inherited from `ArrayAdapter` without considering the no-null thing. when i deleted it, the problem's gone

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue was caused by incremental compile. Just needed to rebuild project after converting from Java.

Answer (score 7):

Please check the sample below:

```
override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View? {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent)
}

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View? {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent)
}

fun getCustomView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View? {
    val rootView: View? = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_custom_view, parent, false)
    return rootView
}
```

The returned value should be nullable.

Comment: It was caused by incremental compile.

Comment: @DawidHyży: Pls, post this (your comment) as answer and accept it. Here happened the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800225/variable-is-declared-as-var-but-compiler-is-saying-it-val/44801687#44801687

Comment: My problem was the Java to Kotlin auto-converter, which does not infer the safe call operator (?).
"One does not simply paste java code into a Kotlin class/file"

Comment: Perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just had to add the "?" to the convertView parameter

```
override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
```

Answer (score -2):

```
override fun getView(i: Int, view: View, parent: ViewGroup): View {

var itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_dashbord_data, parent, false)

        return itemView
    }
```

// change name of View object (itemView) differ from getView second object (view). so change view to itemView or other name